# does Exchange 2010 come with Outlook License?

Tags: exchange, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can you help me with my software licensing question?](https://serverfault.com/questions/215405/can-you-help-me-with-my-software-licensing-question)

I remember that back in exchange 2003 the server license also allow installation of 50 outlook clients (or at least so  I was told) 
Is there such licensing  on the new exchange 2010?

Comment: Licensing questions are best directed to your local Microsoft rep or reseller, no one here can give an answer that's guaranteed to be correct.

Comment: I know, but I thought there is some "standard licensing" like the Server 1 real & 1 virtual machine license

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Outlook licenses are not incorporataed with a Exchange license. To use an exchange server with Outlook clients you will need:

- An operating System license
- Server CALS
- An Exchange Server License
- Exchange CALS or Exchange Enterprise CALS depending on the features you are using.
- Outlook licenses

You might be able to buy a part of the cals needed together with the depending server. But you should really talk to an representative.